Modified Dijkstra - Time Complexity?
I am solving the Leetcode Problem 787. Cheapest Flights Within K Stops.
Basically this is single source shortest path, but with max k steps allowed. So, we can't use normal Dijkstra algorithm, where we do not consider a path if we already reached the node with a lower cost. Here it is possible that the lower cost path may exhaust the k steps allowed before reaching Destination and we might have to take a path with greater cost, but that uses lesser number of steps.
I have coded this improvisation of normal Dijkstra algorithms to solve this problem. This solution is accepted but I'm having trouble determining Time Complexity for it.
Approach
In this approach, like normal Dijkstra, I will pull out the node with lowest cost. But while pushing the node, I will push when either cost or stops are getting reduced. In this way paths which might have greater cost but lower steps will get considered eventually.
class Solution {
public:
    int findCheapestPrice(int n, vector<vector<int>>& flights, int src, int dst, int k) {
        // create adj list
        vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> adj(n); //u -> {v, w}
        for(int i = 0; i < flights.size(); i++)
        {
            adj[flights[i][0]].push_back({flights[i][1], flights[i][2]});
        }

        // Dijkstra

        // the below cost[i], stops[i], store the cost, stops for node i at some moment, these
        // are not necessarily the min cost , or lowest stops for node i
        vector<int> cost(n, INT_MAX);  
        vector<int> stops(n, INT_MAX); 
        priority_queue<array<int, 3>, vector<array<int, 3>>, greater<array<int, 3>>> minheap;
        cost[src] = 0;
        stops[src] = 0;
        minheap.push({cost[src], src, stops[src]});
        while(!minheap.empty())
        {
            auto [ucost, u, ustops] = minheap.top();
            minheap.pop();

            // when we process the node, it is sure that cost of that node can't be improved,
            //  although it may be possible to reach node with lesser number of stops
            if(u == dst) 
                return ucost; 

            // we already used up k stops, can't go further
            if(ustops == k + 1)
                continue;
            
            for(auto &[v, edgecost] : adj[u])
            {
                // we found a better cost or better stops, we'll consider that path
                if(cost[v] > ucost + edgecost ||stops[v] > ustops + 1)
                {
                    cost[v] = ucost + edgecost;
                    stops[v] = ustops + 1;
                    minheap.push({cost[v], v, stops[v]});
                }

            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
};

The problem with determining TC for this is that, the a node can be pushed multiple times into the minheap - as cost gets reduced, we update cost and stops | now next time stop gets reduced, we update cost and stops (cost gets increased again in this) | now next time cost can get reduced again,
and so we are not going into any fixed pattern of reducing cost or reducing stops for a node.
Is there a systematic way I can analyse time complexities of the above approach.
Edit 1: removed multiple approaches, to keep this question focused on 1 approach.

Please focus on one question only: so in this case only ask about one approach, not two. You can ask a new question for a second approach.

@trincot correct. I removed one approach. If possible please have a go at the question now. Thanks.

@Unmitigated, my goal is not to get solution accepted, but determine the actual time complexity. so doesn't matter if the actual test cases are not that big.

TC is ~O(k * E logV) or simply ~O(E logV) and SC is ~O(E + k * V) or simply ~O(E + V). E is for edges and V for vertices.

It is O(E * k * log(k * V)) because the priority queue operation occur at most once for each vertex-edge pair and each vertex can be inserted into the priority queue up to k + 1 times. The extract-min operation on a priority queue O(k * V) so we get O((k+1) * E * log(k * V)) or O(E * k * log(k * V))

I am not able to offer a rigorous proof but only an intuition.
Instead of considering a constrained Dijkstra's algorithm, we could instead reformulate the problem to running the original Dijkstra's algorithm on a modified graph. For vertex vi in the original graph (except the source vertex), we can decompose it into k vertices vi, 1, vi, 2, …, vi, k, each should be reached from the source vertex with no more than 1, 2, …, k steps. Then, for an edge connecting vi and vj in the original graph, edges connecting vi, l and vj, l + 1, for all 1 ≤ l < k are added to the new graph. The source vertex would still just be one vertex in the new graph, but connected to the "1-step" vertices corresponding to its original neighbor. Now the original problem would be equivalent to finding the shortest path on the new graph starting from the source to the "k-step" vertex corresponding to the original destination vertex.
Thus, the modified Dijkstra's algorithm you wrote is effectively a standard Dijkstra running on the new graph. As the new graph has about k|E| edges and k|V| vertices, while the standard Dijkstra has time complexity of O(|E|log |V|), the modified Dijkstra indeed has the time complexity of O(k|E|log |V|) as pointed out in the comment by user24714692.
However, I haven't come up with a rigorous proof demonstrating how running your modified the Dijkstra is equivalent to running the standard Dijkstra on the original graph yet. Intuitively, it makes sense that for a vertex vi, a shortest path using t vertices (for some t) would be discovered first, then a shortest path using t − 1, t − 2, t − 3, … edges (it may not even be in steps of -1, -2, but could be for example, -5, -8). Thus, vi in your code would function as vi, t, vi, t − 1, vi, t − 2, … in the new graph that I constructed above, as the algorithm runs.
